# position fixed on bootstrap 'affix' not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I added [this plugin](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dot-navigation-with-tooltips) to [this website](http://sunergarcia.com/tempimpex/). The issue that i am having that i cant have the navigation stay fixed on the website for some reason, you can see the little navigation when you scroll down but it does not stay fixed like in the plug in.

does anyone have a way i could resolve this, thank you very much!

Here is the class

```
#dot-nav{    
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nav is positioned fixed to the most nearest relative position item, that is the div with class page-wrapper is 3673 pixels height so the position top:50% is actually doing it well to the middle of that div.

The easiest solution for your problem is to take the whole #dot-nav item outside the page-wrapper and it will work well. Put it after the page-wrapper.